# Bessel Function Analytic Continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, integers, bessel-functions, analytic-continuation

The analytic continuation of the first Hankel function is given by (abramowitz_and_stegun): $H^{(1)}_{n}(ze^{m\pi i})=(-1)^{mn-1}((m-1)H^{(1)}_{n}(z)+mH^{(2)}_{n}(z))$ where m,n are integers and z is a complex number.

My question is the following: For $m=\pm1$ I would expect to obtain the same result for $H^{(1)}_{n}(-z)$. But this does not seem to be the case:

For $m=+1$ we have: $$H^{(1)}_{n}(ze^{\pi i})=(-1)^{n-1}(H^{(2)}_{n}(z))$$ and for $m=-1$ we have $$H^{(1)}_{n}(ze^{-\pi i})=(-1)^{-n-1}(-2H^{(1)}_{n}(z)-H^{(2)}_{n}(z))$$ I would expect to have $H^{(1)}_{n}(ze^{\pi i})=H^{(1)}_{n}(ze^{-\pi i})$ but this leads to $H^{(1)}_{n}(z)+H^{(2)}_{n}(z)=0\rightarrow J_{n}(z)=0$ where $J_{n}(z)$ is a Bessel function defined as $J_{n}(z)=\frac{1}{2}(H^{(1)}_{n}(z)+H^{(2)}_{n}(z))$

I am sure there is a subtle difference between the two cases $m=\pm1$, but I can't find it. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Writing this equation down with $m = 1$ and then again with $m = -1$ is straightforward.  It is exceptionally unclear why you believe doing so "does not seem to be the case".  Also, a potentially more useful reference would be "[10.11.7 from the DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.11.E7)".

Comment: Yes I used that reference. But when substituting m=1 and m=-1 the right-hand side does not yield the same/equal result. Thus clearly $H^{(1)}_{n}(ze^{\pi i})$ is not the same as $H^{(1)}_{n}(ze^{-\pi i})$ which I don't understand because they should both be equal to $H^{(1)}_{n}(-z)$

Comment: $$ \mathrm{e}^{\pi \mathrm{i}} = -1 = \mathrm{e}^{-\pi \mathrm{i}}  \text{.}  $$  See [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: yes that's what I am saying. So why aren't the right-hand side of the initial equation equal to each other??

Comment: Still can't make out what you are expecting to be different ... and from what.  It might be helpful to amplify your question with a fully written out version of what you get when you substitute $m = \pm 1$ as well as what you are expecting to get so it is clear what distinction you are making.

Comment: The thing is that these functions are multivalued functions and better defined on the Riemann surface of the logarithm (the universal covering space of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left\{0\right\}$). $e^{\pi i}$ and $e^{-\pi i}$ are two different elements on the surface, there is no such thing as $-1$ on it. Think about the $\sqrt{z}$. It gives different outputs for these two elements.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, the purpose of this formula is to tell you how the value of the function changes as you go up or down on the different Riemann sheets (by rotating the phase of the argument). That is why it is called analytic continuation.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! This makes a lot of sense. Just a follow-up. Would the principle value of the analytic continuation be for the case m=1, or is this arbitrary? In other words, are we allowed to pick whichever branch is more convenient for our use? Thanks!

Comment: The usual representations (e.g., integral formulae) are for the principal branch. You can use the analytic continuation formulae to determine the value of the functions on other sheets. Note that in the analytic continuation formula you quoted, $z$ need not to be on the principal sheet.